# PHP - Facebook API Can't get non Public Posts

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying get data post in fan page, which the post is non-public. but this result is `{"data":[]}`

this is my code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxx',
  ));  
$page = $facebook->api("/KataMutiaraKomikNarutokmkn/posts?limit=5","GET");
print_r($page)
```

but, when i'm trying using tools explorer, page content is available
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

what wrong with my code ?

thanks before :)

Comment: Probably because you're logged in on Facebook which does the API call with your credentials. But not in your API call?

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER oh ok, how if without login on facebook ?